# binding value in hiddenfield using Eval

Tags: asp.net, eval, hiddenfield

I am using this code in my website, where it gives me the parser error, "The server tag is not well formed."

`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfFirstName" Value='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Title").ToString()) ? Eval("FirstName") : (Eval("Title").ToString().Split(' ')[0]) %>' />`

please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.Split(' ')` try using `.Split(" ".ToCharArray())`.

That should get rid of the parser error you're seeing.